# Check has undo/redo backbone undo

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, undo-redo

I am using [backbone](https://github.com/osartun/Backbone.Undo.js) undo js for `undo` and `redo`,I need to check whether undo or redo is available.
is there any method like `hasundo()` and `hasredo()`

```
   View = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                // If the model's value changes, update the view
                this.model.on("change:value", function (model, value, options) {
                    if (value != this.$el.html()) {
                        this.$el.html(value);
                        //need to check here,and add code for enable or disable my undo/redo buttons

                    }
                }, this);
            }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check this "manually" by seeing if the attribute exists and is of type "function".

See this answer: [Javascript check if function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists/1042154#1042154)

Comment: Then what you should do is write a `hasUndo` function in your model, and only show the "undo" button in the view if `this.model.hasUndo()` is true.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `isAvailable` function built right into Backbone.Undo.js specifically for your use case. [Read the documentation here](https://github.com/osartun/Backbone.Undo.js#isavailable--------undomanagerisavailabletype). You just need to write

> if (myUndoManager.isAvailable("undo")) { /* doSomething */ }

As this question is almost four months old you probably already solved this problem somehow. However, I still wanted to drop the answer here for completeness' sake. Maybe it helps others who stumple upon this thread. :)