# How do I cast to an interface an object may implement?

Tags: interface, typescript

I have the following classes & interfaces:

```
export interface IBody {
    body : ListBody;
}

export class Element  {
// ...
}

export class Paragraph extends Element implements IBody {
// ...
}

export class Character extends Element {
// ...
}
```

I have code where I will get an array of Element derived objects (there are more than just Paragraph & Character). In the case of those that implement IBody, I need to take action on the elements in the body.

What is the best way to see if it implements IBody? Is it "if (element.body !== undefined)"?

And then how do I access it? "var bodyElement = <IBody> element;" gives me an error.

```
C:/src/jenova/Dev/Merge/AutoTagWeb/client/layout/document/elements/factory.ts(34,27): error TS2012: Cannot convert 'Element' to 'IBody':
    Type 'Element' is missing property 'body' from type 'IBody'.
    Type 'IBody' is missing property 'type' from type 'Element'.
```

thanks - dave

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An `interface` in TypeScript is a compile-time only construct, with no run-time representation. You might find section 7 of the TypeScript specification interesting to read as it has the complete details.

So, you can't "test" for an `interface` specifically. Done correctly and completely, you generally shouldn't need to test for it as the compiler should have caught the cases where an object didn't implement the necessary interface. If you were to try using a type assertion:

```
// // where e has been typed as any, not an Element
var body = <IBody> e;
```

The compiler will allow it without warning as you've asserted that the type is an `IBody`. If however, `e` were an `Element` in scope, the compiler as you've shown will check the signature of the `Element` and confirm that it has the properties/methods declared by `IBody`. It's important to note that it's checking the signature -- it doesn't matter that it may not implement `IBody` as long as the signature matches up.

Assuming that `Element` has a signature that matches `IBody`, it will work. If it does not, you'll get the compiler error you're receiving. But, again, if it's declared as `any`, the assertion will pass and at run-time, unless the type has the methods defined on `IBody`, the script will fail.

As your `Element` is the base class, you *cannot* check for `IBody`. You could declare an argument as `any`:

```
function someFeature(e: any) {

}
```

And then assert that the `IBody` is present:

```
function someFeature(e: any) {
     var body :IBody = <IBody> e;    
     // do something
}
```

However, if you do need a run-time check, you'd need to look for the function on the `prototype` or as a property before using it. While that could be misleading in some cases, the `interface` in TypeScript also may not have caught the mismatch either. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042154/95190)'s an example of how you could check for the existence of a specific function.

It might look like this:

```
function someFeature(e: any) {
    var body = <IBody> e;
    if (typeof (body.someFunctionOnBodyInterface) === "undefined") {
        // not safe to use the function
        throw new Error("Yikes!");
    }

    body.someFunctionOnBodyInterface();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, it might however be good to highlight the fact that typescript is structurally typed. That is; interface IFoo { a: number; } is considered to be the same "type" as IBar { a: number; }, i.e. a function accepting IFoo will happily accept IBar as well.

Comment: OK -- I updated the question to better explain why the type assertion is failing and fixed an important typo about the expected type when doing an assertion. And, the link I included at the bottom has a good suggestion for how to check for the existence of a function/property.

Comment: There's a library now from Victor Savkin for runtime type check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-type-checks