# Add additional information to route - workaround for TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

normally I put some settings into my route. For example:

```
              .when('Products', {
                templateUrl: 'App/Products.html',
                settings: {
                    showbuy: true,
                    showexport: true,
                    Description: "Product List"
                },[...]
```

Since I started with TypeScript and angularJS the Interface of the IRouteProvider brings some limitations regarding the IRouteProvder btw. the IRoute interface. The IRoute interface doesn't provide any properties where I could store my custom settings object.

At the moment I can only set the predefined properties of the IRoute interface like:

```
app.config([
            <any>'$routeProvider', function routes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) { $routeProvider
                    .when('/Product',
                    {
                         templateUrl: 'App/Products.html',
                         controller:'someController'
                         [...]
                    })
```

The angular js ng-route interface is defined as:

```
interface IRouteProvider extends IServiceProvider {     
    otherwise(params: IRoute): IRouteProvider;
    when(path: string, route: IRoute): IRouteProvider;
}
/**
 * see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when    for API documentation
 */
interface IRoute {
    /**
     * {(string|function()=}
     * Controller fn that should be associated with newly created scope or the name of a registered controller if passed as a string.
     */
    controller?: string|Function;
    /**
     * A controller alias name. If present the controller will be published to scope under the controllerAs name.
     */
    controllerAs?: string;
    /**
     * Undocumented?
     */
    name?: string;
    [...]
```

So I asked my self, if there exists a workaround to save a custom object to each defined route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to define a new interface that extends ng.route.IRoute. When the route is declared, cast the route definition as the new interface.

Define a new interface:

```
export interface IPageTitleRoute extends ng.route.IRoute {
    pageTitle: string;
}
```

Define the route casting as the new interface:

```
angular.module('App').config(['$routeProvider',
    function routes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', <IPageTitleRoute> {
                controller: App.Controllers.HomeController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: './views/app/home.html',
                pageTitle: 'Home'
            })
            .otherwise('/');
    }
]);
```

Leverage the new property in appropriate places (like $routeChangeSuccess):

```
angular.module('App').run(['$rootScope', '$location',
    function($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $location: ng.ILocationService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
            function(event: ng.IAngularEvent, current: IPageTitleRoute, previous: ng.route.IRoute) {
                $rootScope['pageTitle'] = current.pageTitle;
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23282208) to a related question regarding casting to an interface useful. Here is a quote:

> An interface in TypeScript is a compile-time only construct, with no run-time representation. You might find section 7 of the TypeScript specification interesting to read as it has the complete details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add arbitrary members to an object literal and it will still match the interface. E.g. the following compiles fine:

```
interface I {}

var i: I = { a: 1 };
```