# Check if functionA of one.js exists from two.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an external js which I call in to the main page. This external file has a function

```
function fruitLib(){
   //do stuff
}
```

I have another external js and there is another function.

```
function price(){
   //do stuff
}
```

Now how can I check if `fruitLib()` exists before calling `price()`? Below is what I tried but doesn't work (maybe because both files are external files).

```
if (typeof fruitLib== 'function') { 
  price(); 
}
```

Comment: Your check is fine if `fruitLib` is a global function. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your reply. None of them are global functions. I just have `functionA` in `one.js` and I want to call `function` of `two.js` only if `functionA` is available.

Comment: For it to be available, it must either be a global function or a value you receive as the result of a function call (for instance, using some kind of AMD).

Comment: Thanks. If `price()` is in the main html file, is it possible to check if `fruitLib()` is available?

Comment: As I said: The check you have will work. It will work if `fruitLib` is a global, and it will work if `fruitLib` is a variable you've received a function reference into. The question makes no sense at present.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. So `$.ab.fruitLib= function(){` would be the solution?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Also in according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists/) `if (typeof $.ab.fruitLib=== "function") { ` would be the safer solution. Any comments on that?.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `fruitLib()` is in file foo.js and `price()` in bar.js, do this in the area that you include your JavaScript files:

```
<script src="foo.js">
<script src="bar.js">
```

That way you know that `fruitLib()` is loaded *before* `price()`.

---

A relevant question lies here: [Javascript check if function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists/).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to check if`fruitLib()` is available, if `price()` is in the main html itself?

Comment: Becky you are welcome, it's a nice question, that's why I am upvoting! Well doesn't the link helps? I have a class now. If you still have issues let me know.