# Error handling in Node.js for calling a function with wrong name

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am requiring a module and saving it in a variable. But when I call a module function by wrong name, it does not throw any error or consoles any error. How do I make this throw error?

```
            var module = require('../pre_process/' + preProcessFolder + '/' + preProcessModule);
            // module -> { XYZ: [Function] }
            //Following does not throw error and doesn't console anything.How to handle/debug this error  
            module['XY'](result, userId)
              .then(function(recData) {

              })
```

I am using q library for promise.

Comment: Is this entire code itself inside a promise's `.then()`? In that case it might be throwing but you may not have a `.catch()` outside. Checkout Bluebird promise library which is great for automatically logging such uncaught errors

Comment: @jondoe: I ask myself, what do you want to do and why? It makes no sense for me, to include a module completely dynamicly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check if a function (provided by a modul) exists. 
You could use `try` like the example here:
[Javascript check if function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists#1042186)

Comment: Should'nt it throw some error if function does not exist and I am trying to call it?

Comment: @johndoe so it isn't throwing even inside a try catch? Are you really sure it doesn't exist? Can you `console.log(typeof module['XY'])` before calling it?

Comment: @jondoe: maybe you can check typeof === "function" like here: http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/