# How to test if a JavaScript function exists with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

What is the simplest writing to test if this a JavaScript function named `openContactSimplifiedAside()` exists or not with Jasmine?

Comment: `typeof openContactSimplifiedAside === 'function'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript check if function exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists)