# Check if a function is a method of a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to determine if a function is a method of a certain class?

I have a `class A` with a method `doesMethodBelongHere`, that takes a function as an argument `method`. I want to determine that `method` is an actual method of `A`.

```js
class A {
  methodA() {
    console.log('method of A');
  }
  
  doesMethodBelongHere(method) {
    // it should return true if `method` argument is a method of A
    return Object.values(this).includes(method);
  }
}

const a = new A(); 
console.log(a.doesMethodBelongHere(a.methodA)); // should return true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if function exists in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/how-to-check-if-function-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: @Liam That isn't remotely close to a dupe for this.

Comment: @Liam Linked duplicate asks the general question, "Does this method exist _at all_?" - The question OP is asking is, "How do I confirm A  is a method of class B?".

Comment: It should return true if it's specifically a method of the specific instance of A? or generally a method of class A?

Comment: @ReuvenChacha `generally a method of class A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get the prototype. Then iterate the prototype properties using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), and [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). If the method is equal to one of the methods on the prototype return `true`:

```js
class A {
  methodA() {
    console.log('method of A');
  }

  doesMethodBelongHere(method) {
    // get the prototype
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    
    // iterate the prototype properties, and if one them is equal to the method's reference, return true
    for(const m of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
      const prop = proto[m];
      if(typeof(prop) === 'function' && prop === method) return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }
}

const a = new A();
Object.assign(a, { anotherMethod() {} }); 
a.anotherMethod2 = () => {};

console.log(a.doesMethodBelongHere(a.methodA)); // should return true

console.log(a.doesMethodBelongHere(a.anotherMethod)); // should return false

console.log(a.doesMethodBelongHere(a.anotherMethod2)); // should return false
```

**Extended classes:**

This solution will also handle methods that comes from an extended class:

```js
class A {
  methodA() {
    console.log('method of A');
  }

  doesMethodBelongHere(method) {
    let proto = this;
    
    // iterate the prototypes chain
    while (proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto), proto && proto !== Object) {
      // iterate the prototype properties, and if one them is equal to the method's reference, return true
      for (const m of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
        const prop = proto[m];
        if (typeof(prop) === 'function' && prop === method) return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}

const c = new C();
Object.assign(c, {
  anotherMethod() {}
});

c.anotherMethod2 = () => {};

console.log(c.doesMethodBelongHere(c.methodA)); // should return true

console.log(c.doesMethodBelongHere(c.anotherMethod)); // should return false

console.log(c.doesMethodBelongHere(c.anotherMethod2)); // should return false
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    class A {
      constructor() {
        this.methodA = this.methodA.bind(this);
        this.doesMethodBelongHere = this.doesMethodBelongHere.bind(this);
      }
     methodA() {
        console.log('method of A');
      }
      
      doesMethodBelongHere(method) {
        // it should return true if `method` argument is a method of A
        return Object.values(this).includes(method);
      }
    }

    const a = new A(); 
    console.log(a.doesMethodBelongHere(a.methodA)); // should return true
```

This was not bound to your class in your `doesMethodBelongHere`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Can it be achieved without explicit binding?

Comment: `this` shifted in the moment of instanciating. Binding `this` to your class keeps the context at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof` operator

```
let isfn = "function" === typeof ( a.methodA );//isfn should be true
isfn = "function" === typeof ( a["methodA"] );//isfn should be true
isfn = "function" === typeof ( a["methodAX"] );//isfn should be false
```

## Edit

```
doesMethodBelongHere( method ) {
    return  "function" === typeof ( this[method.name] )
}
```

Comment: But I pass a reference to a function, the trick is to get its name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the following implementation:

1. Use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) on the constructor prototype (the same accessing `A.prototype`, but in a more generic approach) in order to iterate class methods.
2. Get method name using [method.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)
3. Using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), find whether (1) includes the name of the given method.

   ```
   class A {

       constructor() {
           this.a = 2;
           this.bb = 3;
       }
       methodA() {
           console.log('method of A');
       }

       doesMethodBelongHere(method) {
           // it should return true if `method` argument is a method of A
           return this.constructor.prototype[method.name] === method;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Method names equivalence doesn't imply the same methods.