# Javascript wait until function is defined

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I want to :

1. wait until a function A is defined (it's in a file loaded asynchronusly)
2. then run function B
3. and i'd like to create a generic wrapper for that, so that i can directly make something like `waitFor(functionToWait, functionToExecute)`

   - i have a result for part 1 & 2, but it's based on setTimeout/setInterval, but i'd like to know if there would be a more elegant way (something like a watcher on the waited function)
   - and i have no idea on the second part, especially how to use a string parameter to convert it into a function reference.

Thanks

Comment: `it's in a file loaded asynchronusly` Can you explain this a bit more? Can you show the code that loads the file?

Comment: <script async src="fileContainingFunctionToWait.js">

Comment: Give the `script` tag a `load` listener, which will fire once the script has been downloaded, parsed, and run. Have the other script assign the function to something global, and then when the `load` event fires, you'll be able to call that global function.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is a combination of the answers from: 
[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) and:
[How to check if function exists in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/how-to-check-if-function-exists-in-javascript)

```
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function demo(cb) {
        while(typeof A !== "function") {
            await sleep(1000);
        }
        cb();
    }

    demo(function() { console.log("function A exists"); });

    var A = function() { };
```

Comment: I don't quite get why isn't main processes blocked by awaiting sleepover