# How to check if function exists?

Tags: typescript

I am updating some old Javascript to Typescript. In Javascript you can do the following [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/how-to-check-if-function-exists-in-javascript):

```
if (typeof functionName === "function") { 
    // safe to use the function
    functionName();
}
```

In Typescript this gives a syntax error *"Cannot find name 'updateRadarCharts'"*

I can resolve the issue with a declare statement

`declare var functionName: Function;`

However this doesn't feel like a clean solution because it is possible this won't be declared (hence the check). Is there a cleaner way to do this in TS ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/how-to-check-if-function-exists-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare the function as:

```
declare var functionName: Function | undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

For global augmentation (which seems to be what you are trying to achieve), a user defined type guard usually works well:

```
interface AugmentedGlobal {
  something: SomeType;
}

function isAugmented(obj: any): obj is AugmentedGlobal {
  return 'something' in obj;
}

if (isAugmented(global/**or window*/)) {
  const myStuff = global.something;
}
```