# Testing function's existence doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042154/871404), I'm trying to call my plugin's main function only if it exists, however the test fails despite the function actually existing (the plugin works properly on my page).

I changed my code a bit to perform the test first, then call the function anyway. I should see "yes" in the console since the plugin works, instead I see "no".

What am I doing wrong?

```
if (typeof owlCarousel === 'function') { 
  console.log('yes');
}
else {
  console.log('no');
}
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   items: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if a jQuery plugin exists, you should check if it's defined in the jQuery namespace

```
if ( "owlCarousel" in $.fn && typeof $.fn.owlCarousel === "function") {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add your code for the owlCarousel, inside the if (true) block, this way its not executing on false.

```
if (typeof owlCarousel === 'function') { 
  console.log('yes');
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
     items: 1
  });
}
else {
  console.log('no');
}
```

Try wrapping your code inside document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       if (typeof owlCarousel === 'function') { 
      console.log('yes');
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
         items: 1
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log('no');
    } 
});
```

to allow for your library, to load first.