# Check support for Offscreen canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an HTML/JavaScript SPA and I want to check whether Offscreen canvas is supported by the Browser or not.

I tried with

```
var canvasTest = document.createElement('canvas-test');

if(typeof canvasTest.transferControlToOffscreen === "function")
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

but it doesn't work (i.e. it returns false even though the Browser actually supports it)

I'm using this code to check if the function exists or not:
[How to check if function exists in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/how-to-check-if-function-exists-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you create a `canvas-test` dom element, which is not the same as `canvas`.

Try this.

```js
var canvasTest = document.createElement('canvas');

if(typeof canvasTest.transferControlToOffscreen === "function")
{
   console.log('true');
}
else
{
   console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: yes, silly me. I was thinking of an html id instead of the actual html element. Thanks

Comment: It's a shame that createElement() is so permissive, letting me to create HTML elements that doesn't exist

Comment: In html5 you can create any type of HTML element it's not as strict in this regard as XHTML was.

Comment: For Firefox 88 (and older) the method exists but valling it will throw NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED exception.

Answer (score 5):

you can check the prototype of the canvas which is a much more lightweight way to check than creating a canvas element.

```js
if (HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.transferControlToOffscreen) {
  console.log('support for transferring control of an offscreen canvas exists');
} else {
  console.log('support for transferring control of an offscreen canvas does NOT exist');
}
```

Note that `OffscreenCanvas` and support for transferring a canvas to an offscreen canvas are technically not the same thing. It's possible though probably 0% chance of possibility for a browser to support `OffscreenCanvas` and not support transferring a canvas's control to one. So technically to check for `OffscreenCanvas` support you'd do this

```js
if (typeof OffscreenCanvas !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('OffscreenCanvas is supported');
} else {
  console.log('OffscreenCanvas is NOT supported');
}
```