# JavaScript check typeof dynamically

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if function is defined or not dynamically. I have a **functionName** variable which can be dynamicly changed...
Here is my code:

```
function callback_user_login(object, status) {
    handle_simple_message(object);
}

var functionName = "callback_user_login";
console.log(typeof functionName); // returns string
```

How can I pass dynamicly named function name to **typeof**?

Comment: try to assign functionName to callback_user_login without the string ""

Comment: `var functionName = callback_user_login`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if function exists in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/how-to-check-if-function-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: @christian-moen as I mentioned, I want to check dynamicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its in the global scope you can check

```
    window[varName]
```

or

```
    globalThis[varName]
```