# Check for native defined functions with prototype

Tags: javascript, function, built-in

The answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85815/how-to-tell-if-a-javascript-function-is-defined) says to use this to check if function is defined:

```
typeof yourFunction === 'function'
```

But I've tried this on a non-standard function [link()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link). And actually this returned false. The function is available on every browser I've tried - IE, Chrome, Opera, FireFox.

```
typeof String.link === 'function' // false
typeof String.link() === 'function' // Uncaught error ...
```

Then somewhere I find:

```
typeof String.prototype.link === 'function' //true
```

which actually returns true. What is the difference and why the first one fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` is a constructor function, and functions are also objects. You can append properties to it.

[For example:](http://jsfiddle.net/xdeJN/)

```
function foo(){
    alert('from foo');
}

foo.bar = function(){
    alert('bar on foo');
}

foo();     //from foo
foo.bar(); //bar on foo
```

It's the same reason how jQuery's `$` acts like an object (eg. `$.each()`) and like a function as well (eg. `$(selector)`).

And so:

- using `String.link` is accessing a property of the constructor function itself - which does not exist.
- using `String.prototype.link` accesses the `link()` function that comes with every string - which does exist (and which you should use)

Comment: I thought about it, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript) actually helped, and actually `typeof String().link === 'function'` returns true. This way String will create an empty object and link "availability" should be checked against it.

Comment: @Milo but you'd be creating an object just to check for `link` rather than check for `link` directly in the prototype.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think in that way! This is more practical.

Answer (score 0):

Because string is the Object and doesn't have the link() method. Only the strings have this method. Look:

```
String//Defines the Object
String.prototype//Defines the methods and properties that will be bound to a var of the type String
'foo'//This is a string
'foo'.link//So it has the link method
String//This is an Objecy that defines the strings
String.link//So it doesn't have the link method
String.prototype//An object that stores the methods and properties of the vars of type String
String.prototype.link//So it has the link method
```