# check if a javascript function is exist or is defind

Tags: javascript, function

I want to know whether a function is exist or is defined before i call it.

I have this line of code:

```
function renderView(){
 // some code
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85815/how-to-tell-if-a-javascript-function-is-defined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the typeof, it returns `undefined` if it's not defined or out of scope, and `function` if it's a function

```
if ( typeof renderView == 'function' ) {
    // it exists
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for using typeof as an operator and not a function like all the other fools :)

Comment: `//Simple function that will tell if the function is defined or not
    function is_function(func) {
        return typeof window[func] !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(window[func]);
    }

    //usage
    
    if (is_function("myFunction") {
            alert("myFunction defined");
        } else {
            alert("myFunction not defined");
        }`

Comment: That uses jQuery and assumes the function is defined in the global scope ?