# JavaScript variable seems to be treated as function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, referenceerror

I'm developing some JavaScript that will sit on a SharePoint page. SharePoint provides a global function getCurrentCtx(). Unfortunately this function is only available on certain pages. My JavaScript needs to test to see if this function exists.

Easy, right?

```
if(getCurrentCtx) {
    //Code here
}
```

Not so fast:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getCurrentCtx is not defined

WTF? If it's not defined, it should be `undefined` which is falsey and so the if statement should simply be skipped.

```
console.log(getCurrentCtx)
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getCurrentCtx is not defined

As far as I know, the uncaught referencerror exception occurs when you try to call a function that doesn't exist. So why am I getting it when I'm just trying to retrieve the value of a variable?

Thanks,

YM

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370622/2055998) provides the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that are not declared throw the `Uncaught ReferenceError` exception.  Undefined properties return `undefined`. Something like this will probably work.

```
if(typeof getCurrentCtx !== "undefined") {
    //Code here
}
```

Alternately, the following might also work.

```
if(self.getCurrentCtx) {
    //Code here
}
```

Both of these are untested on Sharepoint, but would work in plain JavaScript.

Comment: I'm giving this one the green tick because it mentons the distinction between variables and properties. Attempting to access the variable as a property of the window object is easier for me than doing a typeof.

Answer (score 3):

> As far as I know, the uncaught referencerror exception occurs when you try to call a function that doesn't exist.

Incorrect.

If you are trying read the value of **any** variable (or more general, binding) that doesn't *exist* (e.g. no `var getCurrentCtx` anywhere), then JS throws a reference error.

[Relevant part in the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7).

Exception: [`typeof getCurrentCtx` would return `"undefined"`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3), because it tests whether the variable (reference) is resolvable (exists) before it reads it.

Comment: Variables at don't exist are undeclared. (And since `typeof` doesn't need the variable to be declared, the OP can use it in their `if` statement).

Comment: Oh interesting, I never knew that. Thanks!