# JSON stringify ignoring parameters in different tabs same browser

Tags: javascript, zabbix

I need to beautify an existing view through a userscript (TamperMonkey). The code works in JSFiddle (see http://jsfiddle.net/2phrogm5/), but not where I need it: inside the Zabbix web interface.

To replicate the issue:

- open [the public demo](https://zabbix.org/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.view)
- press F12 to open the Developer Tools
- insert

```
JSON.stringify({"asd": {"asd": 3}}, null, 4)
```

Expected result:

```
"{
    "asd": {
        "asd": 3
    }
}"
```

My output:

```
"{"asd":{"asd":3}}"
```

The issue doesn't exist using Developer Tools on https://stackoverflow.com/.

I already tried the solution provided in [JSON.stringify() array bizarreness with Prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-array-bizarreness-with-prototype-js), with no success.

Comment: it's the same thing booth of your results, just differently written in 1 line and 4 lines

Comment: @Patte that's not the same: notice the additional spaces, and how stringify is supposed to add formatting when called with 3 parameters.

Comment: Welcome Iron, it looks like someone is overwriting JSON.stringify, why don't you load a polyfill at the end to have it back or implement your own.

Comment: @gengns your hint was righ: `frontends/php/jsLoader.php: 'var _json_stringify = JSON.stringify;'.'JSON.stringify = function(value) {'.` is the culprit! So the solution is to use `_json_stringify`. Now.. should I answer my own question, or close it?

Comment: I'm glad that pointed you to the right direction ^^ Of course, it will be helpful if you answer you own question, others can have similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the Zabbix web interface, you can see where the method is overwritten:

```
zabbix-software$ egrep -iR "JSON.stringify *="
frontends/php/jsLoader.php:             'var _json_stringify = JSON.stringify;'.
frontends/php/jsLoader.php:             'JSON.stringify = function(value) {'.
```

The original function is still available, just with a different name: `_json_stringify()`. The updated jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/u7r8q19g/

## update

in Zabbix 5 they put the thing back where it came from or so help me, so now I'm doing:

```
            if (typeof _json_stringify === "function") {
                item.html(_json_stringify(JSON.parse(text), undefined, 4))
            } else {
                item.html(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(text), undefined, 4))
            }
```

thx to [How to tell if a JavaScript function is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85815/how-to-tell-if-a-javascript-function-is-defined)