# Is there a way to call a function conditional on its existence other than `function && function()`?

Tags: javascript

I have times in my JS code where a function may be undefined, and I want to call it only if it's defined. I write `function && function()`. Is there a more concise way to do this? Something like `function.callIfExists()`?

Comment: You can use the optional chaining for this. `function?.()`

Comment: Ask yourself why a function may be undefined and rather fix that? Sounds like an unsound program structure.

Comment: What if it's a function param, which maybe exposed to the client? @deceze

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71755388/3001761